Triangle inequality for $l^2$ norm
While working trough exercises in Peter Lax' book on Functional Analysis, I got stuck on the following exercise from section 5:
Exercise 1: Show that $|(z,u)|'=(|z|^2+|u|^2)^{1/2}$ is a norm on $Z\oplus U$, where $(z,u)\in Z\oplus U$, and $Z,U$ are normed linear spaces.
I managed to show Positivity and Homogeneity, but for subadditivity I'm stuck. Note that we haven't seen any inner products, so we can't use the Cauchy Schwarz Inequality, since it wouldn't make sense in this situation.
I managed to show it using Minkovski, but I feel like this is circular reasoning, like in this answer.
I get that I want:
$|(z,u)+(z',u')|'\leq|(z,u)|'+|(z',u')|'$, and I see that I can get
$$|(z,u)+(z',u')|'=|(z+z',u+u')|'=(|z+z'|^2+|u+u'|^2)^{1/2}$$
But I don't see how to proceed without using any of the for mentioned strategies.

"The same norm?" Two different horned spaces can't have "the same norm," but it is true whether the norm is the "same" or not.

You now just need $\sqrt{a + b} \leq \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}$ - prove it for non-negative $a, b$, and find what $a$ and $b$ should be to get inequality you need.

Not sure why $(|z+z'|^2+|u+u'|^2)^{1/2}\leq(|z|^2+|z'|^2+|u|^2+|u'|^2) ^{1/2}$, would like clarification

@ThomasAndrews You are right. It's meant to be two normed spaces, so the properties for norm go for both spaces. I'll edit my question

@mihaild I know about that inequality and how to show it. I see the solution now as well, I did think of this, but didn't really apply it.. thank you

@fGDu94 since $|\cdot|$ are norms on $Z$ and $U$, it follows by their subadditivity, Lax also uses this notation, although the norms are different!

yes but it is to the power 2, not power 1

@fGDu94 You are right, but this last step is not needed with mihaild's comment. Thanks for the insight! If no one claims it, I will upload an answer tomorrow using the comments so that others with the same problem can use this.

I though I saw the solution using mihaild's comment, but I've been getting stuck for 2 hours now, I don't see how to get the result.

Let $T:Z\oplus U\to \mathbb{R}^2$ be defined by $T(z,u)=(\|z\|,\|u\|),$ where $\mathbb{R}^2$  is equipped with $\ell^2$ norm. Then $$\|T(z+z',u+u')\|_2\le \|T(z,u) +T(z',u')\|_2\\ \le \|T(z,u)\|_2+\|T(z',u')\|_2\quad  (*)$$  The first inequality follows from the triangle inequalities in $Z$ and $U,$ while the second from the triangle inequality in $\mathbb{R}^2.$
The formula $(*)$ is identical with
the desired triangle inequality.
Remark The conclusion holds when $\ell^2$ norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is replaced by any norm satisfying the monotonicity property: if $|z|\le |z'|, |u|\le |u'|$ then $\|(z,u)\|\le \|(z',u')\|.$

Yea, this is similar to the linked post. Although I at first wanted a proof not depending on the $l^2$ norm, since this norm gets defined after the exercise, I think I have to just accept that this is the way to go, thanks for answering.
